# Why is ungrammatical to use "have" instead of "is" after "There"

Tags: sentence-construction

Why can't one just say:

there have a booke over the table just to mean: "there is a book over the table"?

I know it's ungrammatical but seems to be semantical right? it should convey  the table has a book on. Right?

Comment: No, it's not just ungrammatical; it's undecipherable.  **There have....** is (nearly?) always followed by **been**. **There have been numerous incidents in the town.**

Comment: [correction: Why **is it** ungrammatical etc.] There is a book on the table. "over the table" would mean floating in the air. Please check your grammar and spelling. The verb have is for possession or ownership: I have two books. There are two books on the table.

Answer (score 1):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects) explains the construction of a sentence involving a **dummy subject**.

> Sometimes we need to use a ‘dummy’ or ‘empty’ or ‘artificial’ subject when there is no subject attached to the verb, and where the real subject is somewhere else in the clause.

> There **are** five Dutch people in our village. (The real subject is the Dutch people – they are in the village.)

The above sentence is similar to

> Five Dutch people **are** in our village.

To say

> A book **is** on the table.

we could say

> There **is** a book on the table.

Note the consistency in the use of **is** in the two sentences.

We do not say "There has a book..."

Answer (score 0):

*To be* is a copular verb.  It takes complements that non-copular verbs don't, e.g. adjectives.

> I am hot.   (*I have hot* doesn't make sense or mean the same thing).

This means the subject of "to be" can be things that couldn't ever be objects - e.g. the "dummy" *it* or *there*, or
a prepositional phrase--something that would be part of another sentence.

> There is a book on the table.

> On the table is a book.

*Have* is not copular so its subject has to be something that *could* be an object (not of that sentence but just where it possibly could function as an object at all).

> I have a book on the table.

> The park has 10 trees.